# how to add text to top of html code with a wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to make a wordpress plugin, which displays my copyright at the top of the html code.
so if anyone goes on my website and has a look on my website, i can display something like "made with love by my name"

the text should be only visible in the code and not be shown in the front-end.

i know it would be easier to just write the sentence in the html code, but i am trying to make a Wordpress plugin...

and Tips how i could do it? i am a very beginner with php and wordpress.

i created the basis of my plugin with this "plugin-Template"

https://github.com/hlashbrooke/WordPress-Plugin-Template

would be nice if someone could tell me in which .php? file i have to put which code.

i already tried displaying it with echo, but it didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

You should just edit the Wordpress theme and just put it in a HTML comment inside at the beginning of the file (`index.php`).

```html
<!-- MADE BY YOUR_NAME -->
```

Comment: yes, but i really want to get started with writing own wp-plugins.. so i think this is a good option to get in touch with it

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things around your lines that can be ambiguous, but if you had the structure go to /index.php and change these

```
<?php
// phpcs:ignorefile
// Silence is golden. 
echo '<!-- i need to learn how to walk before to run -->';
```

You will see this one line in the code (if the your plugin has been activated) because echo (php) prints an output that does no shows coz this is a COMMENT with the sintaxis of HTML a language to PRINT AN OUTPUT to the user.

Hope it helps, and keep trying all days!